# Create a list of Missing Numbers(integers) using C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to create a list of Missing numbers between 1 and 7000.

My list contains numbers like

1,2,3,4,5,6....upto 80

100, 101, 102, 103....upto 130

200, 201, 202, 203, 204...upto 250

In this case, I want to create from 81 to 99 and 131 to 199 and 251 to 7000.

I tried the below code.

```
var existedNumbers = sections.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();

var list = new List<int>();

 var finalList = list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 9997).Except(existedNumbers);
```

How can I do this using C#

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Comment: Show us what you have tried ?

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 I posted the code

Comment: @Chatra What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Chatra Ok, I'll take it back, but you have to realize that your question before you posted your code looked like you didn't try anything.

Answer (score 2):

you can easily find missing numbers using LINQ:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,80)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(100,31))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(200,51))
    .ToList();
var missing = Enumerable.Range(1,7000)
    .Except(list)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
var seq = Enumerable.Range(1, 7000);
var givenSeq = new List<int>() {1,2,3};  //Given seq
var missingseq = seq.Except(givenSeq);
```